# ListBox Delay Input times

Tags: c#, timer, listbox, delay, keycode

I am trying to figure out how to set a delay between the different Items that are being listed.

When I run my program and type "Connect:192.168.1.1" I want it to say "Connecting" and 2-5 seconds later say "Connected" is there a way to do this or a simpler way to do this all together?

Thank you for your help in advance!

```
        private void ConsoleEnter_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (ConsoleEnter.Text == ("Connect: 192.168.1.1"))
        {
            COMBOX.Items.Add(ConsoleEnter.Text);

            COMBOX.Items.Add("Connected");

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
               ConsoleEnter.Text = "";                   
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do some processing, you can use the `Timer` and start it before performing the task and and then stop after the job is done and then calculate the elapsed time and then display it in seconds to the user.

In case of purposeful delay, you can make that thread to sleep and then resume later.

Please post what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am making a simple hacker type simulation for a school project. What I am doing with this is just a simple screen showing something connecting to "192.168.1.1" and showing that it connected. It's not actually connecting to anything it is just a demonstration for the class. I was just trying to make it look a little better. Because this code here says "Connecting" and "Connected" at the same time. I just wanted to put a 2 to 5 second pause in there to simulate a connection trying to establish.